# How to control a stage play based on previous stage result without using artifacts?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

We have a project hosted on an internal Gitlab installation.

The Pipeline of the project has 3 stages:

- Build
- Tests
- Deploy

The objective is to **hide or disable** the Deploy stage **when Tests fails**

[image]

The problem is that we can't use artifacts because they are lost each time our machines reboot.

My question: Is there an alternative solution to artifacts to achieve this task?

The used `.gitlab-ci.yml` looks like this:

```
stages:
    - build
    - tests
    - deploy

build_job:
    stage: build
    tags:
        # - ....
    before_script:
        # - ....
    script:
        # - ....
    when: manual
    only:
        - develop
        - master

all_tests:
    stage: tests
    tags:
        # - ....
    before_script:
        # - ....
    script:
        # - ....
    when: manual
    only:
        - develop
        - master


prod:
    stage: deploy
    tags:
        # - ....
    script:
        # - ....
    when: manual
    environment: prod
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might have misunderstood the purpose of the built-in CI. The goal is to have building and testing all automated on each commit or at least every push. Having all tasks set to manual execution gives you almost no advantage over external CI tools like Jenkins or Bamboo. Your only advantage to local execution of the targets right now is having visibility in a central place.

That said there is no way to conditionally show or hide CI tasks, because it's against the basic idea. If you insist on your idea, you could look up the artifacts of the previous stages and abort the manual execution in case something is wrong.

> The problem is that we can't use artifacts because they are lost each time our machines reboot

AFAIK artifacts are uploaded to the master and not saved on the runners. You should be fine having your artifacts passed from stage to stage.

By the way, the default for `when` is `on_success` which means to *execute build only when all builds from prior stages succeed.*

Comment: Thank you it's clear for me. The information you give to me "By the way, the default for when is on_success which means to execute build only when all builds from prior stages succeed." is just what I'm looking for.

Comment: As described here https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/yaml/#when
> on_success - execute build only when all builds from prior stages succeed. This is the default.

Comment: Can I combine (somehow) `on_success` and `manual` options.
The objective is to build execution only on_success **and** manually? Because I don' want to go in production each time I do a commit (even when tests are green).

Comment: I recommend packaging your app after every commit, but deploy only manually. If there is no package to deploy, the manual execution will fail. In literature this is sometimes also described as "deployment and release". This means you set up your app on production server automatically and push the switch to use it (e.g. in a load balancer) manually.